# Improve search performance in SQL Server through Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using SQL Server 2012 Express, Entity Framework 6 and the ASP.NET MVC 5.

In SQL Server I've got a `pricelist` table with 400 thousand records. The structure of the pricelist is below:

```
|Id|Manufacturer|Name|Description|StockQuantity|PriceId|
```

Also I've got a `price` table:

```
|Id|Price|CurrencyId|
```

And a `currency` table:

```
|Id|Name|Alias|Value|
```

The `Name` and `Description` columns are indexed by a SQL Server full text index.

I need to get 20 records from the `pricelist`, where `Name` or `Description` **contain** the search query and return it as XML. And I need to get them less then a second, because it's one of the condition from the global search service (it's request timeout is 1 second and I can't change it). This is the structure of a result XML:

```
<items>
    <item mfr="PC" Name="Laptop" Description="2.4GHz, etc." StockQuantity="500" P1="100" P2="200" P3="300" Cur="USD"/>
</items>
```

Where `P1`, `P2` and `P3` are prices for a different order's quantity.

I'm using this code to get records:

```
using (var db = new DatabaseContainer()) {
    db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    var result = 
        (from pricelistRow in db.EFPricelist
        where pricelistRow.Name.Contains(search) || pricelistRow.Description.Contains(search)
            select new Result {
            Manufacturer = pricelistRow.Manufacturer,
            Name = pricelistRow.Name,
            Description = pricelistRow.Description,
            StockQuantity = pricelistRow.StockQuantity,
            P1 = pricelistRow.EFPricelistRowPrice.Any() ? SqlFunctions.StringConvert(pricelistRow.EFPricelistRowPrice.Min(x => x.Price)) : "",
            P2 = pricelistRow.EFPricelistRowPrice.Count() == 3 ? SqlFunctions.StringConvert(pricelistRow.EFPricelistRowPrice.OrderBy(x => x.Price).Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Price) : "",
                P3 = pricelistRow.EFPricelistRowPrice.Count() > 1 ? SqlFunctions.StringConvert(pricelistRow.EFPricelistRowPrice.Max(x => x.Price)) : "",
                Cur = pricelistRow.EFPricelistRowPrice.Any() ? pricelistRow.EFPricelistRowPrice.FirstOrDefault().EFCurrency.Alias : ""
                    }).Take(20).ToList();
    return new XmlResult(new Result {
        Items = result
    });
}
```

And it took about 2 seconds. How can I improve the performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use contains. This is totally not a Entity Framework issue - but SQL.

> pricelistRow.Name.Contains(search)

translates into a WHERE [Name] LIKE '%searchterm%'

see the % in front? that means full data scan and an index does not help.

Alternatives:

- StartsWith (LIKE 'searchterm%'), so an index works
- Using a stored procedure (no other way in EF) and then full text index syntax (which EF can not deal with).

But otherwise - that just does not work. Where conditions like that mean - in your case - a full table scan. Period.

Comment: `StartsWith` saved about 0.5 sec for me and reduce result to one record (which is incorrect for my data sample). Can I just execute plain SQL command through `ExecuteSqlCommand` instead of using a stored procedure (I never used them) for a full text index query?

Comment: @coshmos: "I never used them" is not a good reason not to use stored procedures :)

Comment: @DavidKhaykin, ok, I'll try them :)

Comment: @TomTom, I'll mark your answer when I'll try store procedure. Till saturday. Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that startswith only works good with an index - otherwise it still is a scan - and ful ltext needsd a table scan.